# Function in VMO$(S^1,S^1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I try to find a function $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ that is in [VMO](http://www.mat.ufpb.br/jmbo/papers/Brezis/brezis/brenir95.pdf) but not continous. Does someone have a clue?
VMO: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-207-00/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3.pdf

Yours,
Maxi

Comment: ok? everythink seems fine for me. However I added a second link.